# Activity from a background activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Am having an application contains activity A,B,C and A is launched from the browser and B is launched from A, a count timer running on A launches an activity C if the timer hits. Could any one plz tell the stack order for the activity of this application. either A->B->C or A->C->B. However now the visible activiy should be C if i press back key from C which should display either A or B ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to launch B from A and C from A with

```
startActivityFromChild(this, intentOfC, REQ_CODE_FOR_C);
```

I'm not sure it may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This order is depends upon the launch mode of your activity